# Neo4j dijkstra with pre calculated cost

Tags: neo4j

I'm building a  directions like app and I'm using Neo4j as my database 
I've been struggling to find a solution that can help me doing what i want in Neo4j. I searched a lot and i couldn't find what i need .

The user has the possibility to chose the starting and ending point and to costumize the way he wants his path to be generated. The path ( shortest one) will be generated based on distance , pollution and noise . The user will be able to assign percentages to the three options . 
Giving an example : 
The cost to calculate the shortest path will be : cost = ( distance * 0.25 ) + ( noise_level * 0.25 ) + (pollution_level * 0.5) for each 
 This means that the relationships cost property will be always be dynamic .

I'm using the apoc.algo.dijkstra procedure to help me with it. But  dijkstra only allows me to give the relationships property name . Is there a way to do it ? 
Relationship example between two nodes :

{
"intersectionNode": 25632284,
"polution_level": 2,
"intersection_distance": 0.0,
"noise_level":5,
"cost":0
}

I'm kinda new at Neo4j and any help would be appreciated . Sorry for any English error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be to:

(1) Generate a new calculated weight property in each relevant relationship.

(2) Run your dijkstra query using that calculated weight property.

(3) Optionally, delete the calculated weight properties. (If they are not deleted, their values can become invalid over time, so the values should not be reused.)

Comment: Hi @cybersam . Thank you a lot. That worked as i wanted to ;) 
Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Memgraph](https://memgraph.com), high-performance, in-memory transactional graph database. Memgraph is [openCypher](http://www.opencypher.org) and [Bolt](https://boltprotocol.org) compatible. (DISCLAIMER: I'm the co-founder and CTO). Memgraph has built in weighted shortest path feature where the total weight is calculated via user-defined lambda function. For your case and based on this dataset

```
CREATE (n1 {id: 1}) CREATE (n2 {id: 2}) CREATE (n3 {id: 3}) CREATE (n4 {id: 4})
CREATE (n1)-[:E {pollution_level: 1, distance: 1.0, noise_level: 5}]->(n2)
CREATE (n1)-[:E {pollution_level: 2, distance: 2.0, noise_level: 4}]->(n3)
CREATE (n2)-[:E {pollution_level: 3, distance: 2.0, noise_level: 3}]->(n4)
CREATE (n3)-[:E {pollution_level: 4, distance: 1.0, noise_level: 2}]->(n4);
```

the relevant Memgraph's query would be similar to this one

```
  MATCH (a {id: 1})-[
            edges *wShortest
                (e, n | (e.distance * 0.25) +
                (e.noise_level * 0.25) +
                (e.pollution_level * 0.5))
            total_weight
        ]-(b {id: 4})
  RETURN startNode(head(edges)).id +
         reduce(acc = "", edge IN edges | acc + " -> " + endNode(edge).id) AS hops,
         total_weight;
```

with the following results.

```
| hops      | total_weight |
|-----------|--------------|
|1 -> 2 -> 4| 4.75         |
```